# Unexpected = in PHP snipped I found - how do I fix?

Tags: php

I'm a complete PHP noob, and so I don't know how to troubleshoot this myself. I found this page which I'm trying to implement: http://webdevjunk.com/coding/css/17/php-menu-includes-with-css-style-to-highlight-active-page-link/

I tried to put the snippets into http://www.paulgrantdesign.com/test77/photography/index.php and /test77/photography/includes/nav.php

Why does my index.php say that there's an unexpected "="?

I'd really appreciate the help :)

EDIT: As requested, here's the PHP that's throwing the error

```
<?php $active[$current] = “class=active”; ?>

<div id="nav">
<ul>
<li <?php echo $active[1] ?>><?php if ($current != 1) { echo “<a href="index.php">Home</a>”; } else { echo “Home”; } ?></li>
<li <?php echo $active[2] ?>><?php if ($current != 2) { echo “<a href="about.php">About</a>”; } else { echo “About”; } ?></li>
<li <?php echo $active[3] ?>><?php if ($current != 3) { echo “<a href="how_it_works.php">How it works</a>”; } else { echo “How it works”; } ?></li>
```

There's more, but that gives you the idea of where it's going. Each page on the website has the identifier to say which menu item it's identifying. The identifier looks like this:

```
<?php $current = 3; include ('includes/nav.php'); ?>
```

Comment: Show us the contents of your php file, or simply first line that throws the error.

Comment: Unsure but some code might not be evaluating as expected (perhaps the first line saying “class=active”?). Also, be careful when copy-pasting code like this. The quotes you've posted aren't the same ones that should be used in PHP. In other words `“` is not the same as `"`.

Comment: Lines 5-7 have the same curly quotes problem, plus what metti said in his answer. Programming is hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first PHP lesson:

- Do not copy and paste :) Type in

> ```
> $active[$current] = "class=active";
> ```

instead of copying and pasting it. In fact, I think you will learn more when you type it out.

By the way, the curly quote `“ ”` is what caused the error.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like line 1 has curly quotes:

```
“class=active”
```

You need to change them to normal quotes

```
"class=active"
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you have to escape quotes within quotes or rather use single quotes instead:

```
<?php $active[$current] = "class=active"; ?>

<div id="nav">
<ul>
<li <?php echo $active[1] ?>><?php if ($current != 1) { echo '<a href="index.php">Home</a>'; } else { echo 'Home'; } ?></li>
<li <?php echo $active[2] ?>><?php if ($current != 2) { echo '<a href="about.php">About</a>'; } else { echo 'About'; } ?></li>
<li <?php echo $active[3] ?>><?php if ($current != 3) { echo '<a href="how_it_works.php">How it works</a>'; } else { echo 'How it works'; } ?></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code in the linked article is slightly damaged. PHP uses normal double quotes (`"`) but the article features invalid typographic quotes (`“` and `”`).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `"` character instead of `“` and `”`.